# Proof of alternate definition of derivative in open set

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

In Steven Abbott's Understanding Analysis, there is a question about alternative definition of derivative,

First assume

1. $g:\mathbb{A}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where A is an interval and open.
2. $c\in\mathbb{A}$
3. $g'(c)$ exists

Show that

$\begin{align*}
g'(c)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(c+h)-g(c-h)}{2h}
\end{align*}$

First off I have no idea how is this relateed to an open domain. Second of all, I derived an absurd result.

$\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(c+h)-g(c-h)}{2h}\text{ exists}&\implies\forall (h_n)\subseteq\mathbb{A}\text{ s.t. }\forall n\in\mathbb{N}h_n\neq 0, \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g(c+h_n)-g(c-h_n)}{h_n+h_n}\text{ ,Sequential criterion}\\
&\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g(c+(-h_n))-g(c-h_n)}{h_n+(-h_n)}\text{, since }h_n,-h_n\rightarrow 0\\
&\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g(c+(-h_n))-g(c-h_n)}{0}\text{ exists!!!}
\end{align*}$

There must be something wrong here. But I am just doing according to the sequential criterion of functional limit. I would be grateful if you can point out what's wrong in the inference as well as some tips to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: In applying the sequential criterion, you have to pick the same sequence throughout the limit. Therefore, the step where you picked $h_n$ at one point and $-h_n$ at the other point is not legitimate.

Comment: @KenHung Thank you. May I have some tips as to how should I prove this? Also, how is it related to open interval?

Comment: Maybe I make an answer instead, as it would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in applying the sequential criterion, you have to pick the **same sequence** throughout the limit. Therefore, the step where you picked $h_n$ at one point and $-h_n$ at the other point is not legitimate.

Second of all, the reason of picking an open interval to define differentiability is to ensure that the interval $ [c-h,c+h]$ ($h \neq 0 )$ is contained in $\mathbb{A}$ provided that $h$ is sufficiently small. This will avoid the issue that the limit does not make sense as an expression in the first place.

Comment: Since you have answered 2 of my questions, I will grant your answer to be correct. For future readers, if you want the hint to the problem, please refer to Thomas's solution.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h} =\frac12\left(\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}+\frac{f(x+(-h))-f(x)}{-h}\right)$$

Comment: I am afraid the hint doesn't suffice, at least from my point of view. By applying 1 sequence according to the sequential criterion of functional limit, when I apply $a_n-x$ into $h$, $x+h=a_n$, but $x-h=2x-a_n$, which I can't do anything from a standpoint of $\lim_{a\to x}\frac{g(a)-g(x)}{a-x}$.